# Ajax page refresh error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, submission

The issue is that at form submission through ajax the page still reloads, even though the code has been written for it to not refresh the page, but only a certain div tag. It refreshes the div tag successfully.

As far as I can see (I have quintuple checked) the javascript form submission is written correctly as is the div refresh code.

There might be a problem in the php code where the form and the div that refreshes through ajax are present. The php file and the ajax javascript file are below...

Php file: The div gets refreshed by calling GET ajax=1. The form is called "addmonitor" and the div id is "monitor_form" - located around 2/3 down the bottom of the php code:

```
<?php 
if (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR=='/'){
  define('EZMON_C', dirname(__FILE__));
}else{
  define('EZMON_C', str_replace("\\", '/', dirname(__FILE__)));
}
require_once(EZMON_C.'/admin/local_config.php');

function mak_pwords($string, $saltkey, $pos=15) {
    $stringA        = sha1($string);
    $salt           = md5($saltkey);
    $afterstr       = substr($stringA, $pos);
    $startbeginning = -(strlen($afterstr));
    $beforestr      = substr($stringA, 0, $startbeginning);
    $hex            = '/$E'; // fake ending
    $salted         = $beforestr . $salt . $afterstr . $hex;
    return $salted;
}
//Path to location of local_config.php
error_reporting(0);
// resume the existing session, or establish a new one
session_start();
// Check Login
if(!isset($_SESSION['s_username']) && !isset($_SESSION['s_password']))
{
    header("Location:index.php");
    exit;
}

//$uid = isset($_GET['uid'])?intval($_GET['uid']):0;
// TODO: this is so wrong, but must remain for now. IMPORTANT!!! move this to index.php, where i assume login password checking is performed.
$uid = isset($_GET['uid'])?intval($_GET['uid']):0;
$_SESSION['uid']=$uid;

if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = 1;
}else{
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}

// Added by KTHSoft
if (isset($_GET['ajax'])){
    $get_items     = 'SELECT * FROM servers WHERE user_id=\''.mysql_real_escape_string($uid).'\'';
    $get_items_res = mysql_query($get_items) or die(mysql_error( ));
    $total_items = mysql_num_rows($get_items_res);

    # Define the number of results per page
    $max_results = 10;

    /* Figure out the limit for the query based
    on the current page number. */
    $from = (($page * $max_results) - $max_results);

    # get only the limited results
    $get_limited_items = "SELECT * FROM servers WHERE user_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($uid)."' ORDER BY com_domain ASC LIMIT $from, $max_results";
    $get_limited_items_res = mysql_query($get_limited_items) or die(mysql_error( ));

    echo '<table><b>Monitors:</b></table>';
    echo '<table>';

    $turn = "275";
  $cookies_defined = False;   // Added by Predrag Bradaric (31. March 2011)

   while ($items = mysql_fetch_array ($get_limited_items_res)) 
   {
      $domain      = $items['domain'];
      $com_domain  = $items['com_domain'];
      $port        = $items['port'];
      $last_time   = $items['last_time'];
      $last_date   = $items['last_date'];
      $last_status = $items['last_status'];
      $active      = $items['active'];
      $sid         = $items['id'];

      if($last_status==1) {
         $status = '<td width="10" align="left"><img src="images/rarrow.png" alt="Website Down" title="Website Down" style="margin-top: 2px;"></td>';
      }elseif($last_status == 0){
         if($active == 1){
            if($last_time !=""){
                 $status = '<td width="10" align="left"><img src="images/garrow.png" alt="Website Up" title="Website Up" style="margin-top: 2px;"></td>';
            }else{
                 $status = '<td width="10" align="left"><img src="images/pause.png" alt="Monitoring not started yet" title="Monitoring not started yet" style="margin-top: 2px;"></td>';
            }
            $last_updtt = $last_time;
            $last_updtd = $last_date;
         }
         if($active==0){
            $status = '<td width="10" align="left"><img src="images/pause.png" alt="Website Not Monitored" title="Website Not Monitored" style="margin-top: 2px;"></td>';
         }
      }else{
         $status = '<td>Unknown</td>';
      }
      if($port==80){$port_type="HTTP";
        }elseif($port==21){$port_type="FTP";
        }elseif($port==143){$port_type="IMAP";
        }elseif($port==25){$port_type="SMTP";
        }elseif($port==5060){$port_type="SIP";
        }elseif($port==110){$port_type="POP";
        }elseif($port==443){$port_type="HTTPS";
        }elseif($port==2082){$port_type="cPanel";
        }elseif($port==2086){$port_type="WHM";
        }elseif($port==3306){$port_type="MySQL";
        }else{$port_type=$port;}
      if($last_time==""){
         $last_time="Monitoring not started yet";
      }
      echo '<tr>'.$status
      ?>
      <!-- MODIFIED BY Predrag Bradaric (29. March 2011) -->
    <?php 
        if (!(isset($_GET['donotrefresh']))) {
          if (isset($_COOKIE["$com_domain$port"])) {
            $cookies_defined = True;
          }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (dhtmlwindow.getCookie("<?php echo "$com_domain$port"; ?>")) {
          var window_name = "<?php echo "$com_domain$port"; ?>";
          <?php echo "$com_domain$port"; ?> = dhtmlwindow.open(window_name, dhtmlwindow.getCookie(window_name).split("~")[4], decodeURIComponent(dhtmlwindow.getCookie(window_name).split("~")[5]), dhtmlwindow.getCookie(window_name).split("~")[6], 'width='+dhtmlwindow.getCookie(window_name).split("~")[2]+',height='+dhtmlwindow.getCookie(window_name).split("~")[3]+',left='+dhtmlwindow.getCookie(window_name).split("~")[0]+',top='+dhtmlwindow.getCookie(window_name).split("~")[1]+',resize=0,scrolling=0', 'recal');
        }
//      alert(dhtmlwindow.getCookie("<?php echo "$com_domain$port"; ?>"))
      </script>
      <!-- END OF MODIFICATION (29. March 2011) -->
    <?php } ?>

        <td> <!--
            <a href="#" title="Click to open uptime graph and statistics" onClick="<?php echo "$com_domain"; ?>graphs(); return false"><?php echo $domain; ?></a><?php echo ' ' . $port_type; ?> -->
            <a href="#" title="Click to open uptime graph and statistics" onClick="<?php echo "$com_domain$port"; ?>=dhtmlwindow.open('<?php echo "$com_domain$port"; ?>', 'iframe', 'uptime_display.php?sid=<?php echo $sid; ?>&uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>', 'Monitor <?php echo $domain." ".$port_type; ?>', 'width=446px,height=325px,left=<?php echo $turn; ?>px,top=77px,resize=0,scrolling=0', 'recal'); return false"><?php echo $domain; ?></a><?php echo ' ' . $port_type; ?>
        </td>
      <?php
      # monitor buttons to pause, resume and delete
      if ($active == 1)
      {
        ?>
        <td align="right" width="25" style="font-size: 11px; color: #666;">
        <a href="#" onClick="pausemon=dhtmlwindow.open('pausemon', 'iframe', 'monform.php?sid=<?php echo $sid; ?>&uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>&what=pause', 'Pause monitor <?php echo $domain."?"; ?>', 'width=330px,height=126px,center=1,resize=0,scrolling=0'); return false"><img src="images/control_pause.png" title="Pause monitor: <?php echo $domain; ?>" alt="Pause monitor: <?php echo $domain; ?>" height="16" width="16" border="0"></a></td>
        <!--
        <td align="right" width="25" style="font-size: 11px; color: #666;">
        <a href="#" onClick="pausemon=dhtmlwindow.open('pausemon', 'div', 'monpau', 'Pause monitor <?php echo $domain."?"; ?>', 'width=425px,height=267px,center=1,resize=0,scrolling=0'); return false"><img src="images/control_pause.png" title="Pause monitor: <?php echo $domain; ?>" alt="Pause monitor: <?php echo $domain; ?>" height="16" width="16" border="0"></a></td> -->
        <?php
      }
      else if ($active == 0)
      {
        ?>
        <td align="right" width="25" style="font-size: 11px; color: #666;">
        <a href="#" onClick="resumemon=dhtmlwindow.open('resumemon', 'iframe', 'monform.php?sid=<?php echo $sid; ?>&uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>&what=resume', 'Resume monitor <?php echo $domain."?"; ?>', 'width=330px,height=126px,center=1,resize=0,scrolling=0'); return false"><img src="images/control_play_blue.png" title="Resume monitor: <?php echo $domain; ?>" alt="Resume monitor: <?php echo $domain; ?>" height="16" width="16" border="0"></a></td>
        <!--
        <td align="right" width="25" style="font-size: 11px; color: #666;">
        <a href="#" onClick="resumemon=dhtmlwindow.open('resumemon', 'div', 'monres', 'Resume monitor <?php echo $domain."?"; ?>', 'width=425px,height=267px,center=1,resize=0,scrolling=0'); return false"><img src="images/control_play_blue.png" title="Resume monitor: <?php echo $domain; ?>" alt="Resume monitor: <?php echo $domain; ?>" height="16" width="16" border="0"></a></td> -->
        <?php
      }
      ?>
      <td align="right" width="18" style="font-size: 11px; color: #666;">
      <a href="#" onClick="deletemon=dhtmlwindow.open('deletemon', 'iframe', 'monform.php?sid=<?php echo $sid; ?>&uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>&what=delete', 'Delete monitor <?php echo $domain."?"; ?>', 'width=330px,height=126px,center=1,resize=0,scrolling=0'); return false"><img src="images/delete.png" title="Delete monitor: <?php echo $domain; ?>" alt="Delete monitor: <?php echo $domain; ?>" height="16" width="16" border="0"></a></td>
      <!--
      <td align="right" width="18" style="font-size: 11px; color: #666;">
      <a href="#" onClick="deletemon=dhtmlwindow.open('deletemon', 'div', 'mondel', 'Delete monitor <?php echo $domain."?"; ?>', 'width=425px,height=267px,center=1,resize=0,scrolling=0'); return false"><img src="images/delete.png" title="Delete monitor: <?php echo $domain; ?>" alt="Delete monitor: <?php echo $domain; ?>" height="16" width="16" border="0"></a></td> -->
      <?php

      # set position of windows displaying the graphs
      if ($turn == "275")
      {
        $turn = "730";
      }
      else if ($turn == "730")
      {
        $turn = "275";
      }
   }
   echo "</table>";

    // MODIFIED BY Predrag Bradaric (31. March 2011)
    if (!($cookies_defined) && !(isset($_GET['donotrefresh']))) {
      // init dhtml windows from database
      // at this point $uid should be valid user id
      include("dhtmlretrieve.php");
    }
    // END OF MODIFICATION (31. March 2011)


    # begin page numbers output

    # Figure out the total number of pages. Always round up using ceil()
    $total_pages = ceil($total_items / $max_results);

    # Build Page Number Hyperlinks
    echo "<center><font size=\"2\" color=\"#666666\"face=\"Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif\">Pages of your monitors:<br /></font>";

    if($page <= 7) 
    {
        $from_linkedpage =  1;
        $to_linkedpage = 15;
    }
    else
    {
        if($page > $total_pages - 7)
        {
            $from_linkedpage =  $total_pages - 15;
            $to_linkedpage = $total_pages;
        } 
        else
        {
            $from_linkedpage =  $page - 7; //15*floor($page / 15)+1;
            $to_linkedpage =  $page + 7; //$from_linkedpage + 14;
        }
    }


    if ($to_linkedpage > $total_pages)
    {
        $to_linkedpage = $total_pages;
    }

    if ($from_linkedpage < 1)
    {
        $from_linkedpage = 1;
    }

    // Build Previous Link
    if(($from_linkedpage > 1) || ($page > 1))
    {
        $prev = ($page - 1);
        echo '<a onclick="goToPage(' . $prev . ')" href="#"><b>&lt; Previous</b></a>&nbsp; ';
    } 

    for($j = $from_linkedpage; $j <= $to_linkedpage; $j++)
    {
        if(($page) == $j)
        {
            echo "$j ";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo '<a onclick="goToPage(' . $j . ')" href="#">'.$j.'</a> ';
        }
    } 

    // Build Next Link
    if($page < $total_pages)
    {
        $next = ($page + 1);
        echo '&nbsp;<a onclick="goToPage(' . $next . ')" href="#"><b>Next &gt;</b></a>';
    } 

    echo "</font></center><br>";
?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function goToPage(page){
            var dataString = 'ajax=1&donotrefresh=1&page=' + page + '&uid=<?php echo $uid;?>';
             $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "monpanel.php",
                 data: dataString,
                 success: function(html_data){
                    $('#list_monitors').html(html_data);
                }
             });
        }
    </script>
<?php   
    die();
}
// End added by KTHSoft


/* Temporary config.php replacement */
$uname_admin           = $setting['uname_admin'];
$pword_admin           = $setting['pword_admin'];
$allow_add             = $setting['allow_add'];
$mon_int               = $setting['mon_int'];
$max_fail              = $setting['max_fail'];
$time_out              = $setting['time_out'];
$mon_email             = $setting['mon_email'];
$do_logging            = $setting['do_logging'];
$fully_log             = $setting['fully_log'];
$err_check             = $setting['err_check'];
$email_override        = $setting['email_override'];
$cfg_offset            = $setting['cfg_offset'];
$pingIP_host           = $setting['pingIP_host'];
$ping_delay            = $setting['ping_delay'];
$num_pings             = $setting['num_pings'];
$reliable_test_server  = $setting['reliable_test_server'];
$reliable_test_server2 = $setting['reliable_test_server2'];
$date_format           = $setting['date_format'];
$version               = $setting['version'];
/* End Temporary config.php replacement */
error_reporting(0);
$style='';
$uid = isset($_GET['uid'])?intval($_GET['uid']):0;
$title=' - Viewing  UserID:'.$uid.' Servers Status';
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
$offset = 60 * 60 * 24 * -1;
$ExpStr = "Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT";
header($ExpStr);
include("header.php");

$monthnow = date("m");
$yearnow = date("Y");
/*
# Delete Monitors
if (isset($_GET["act"]) &&  $_GET["act"] == "delete") {
    $del_items="DELETE FROM servers WHERE id='$_GET[sid]' AND user_id='$_GET[uid]'";
    mysql_query($del_items) or die(mysql_error( ));

    #echo '<script>alert("Monitor Deleted Successfully!")</script>';
}

# Pause Monitors
if (isset($_GET["act"]) &&  $_GET["act"] == "pause") {
    $pause_items="UPDATE servers SET active=0 WHERE id='$_GET[sid]' AND user_id='$_GET[uid]'";
    mysql_query($pause_items) or die(mysql_error( ));

    #echo '<script>alert("Monitor Paused Successfully!")</script>';
}

# Resume Monitors
if (isset($_GET["act"]) &&  $_GET["act"] == "resume") {
    $resume_items="UPDATE servers SET active=1 WHERE id='$_GET[sid]' AND user_id='$_GET[uid]'";
    mysql_query($resume_items) or die(mysql_error( ));

    #echo '<script>alert("Monitor Paused Successfully!")</script>';
}
*/
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="windowfiles/dhtmlwindow.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="windowfiles/dhtmlwindow.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="modalfiles/modal.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="modalfiles/modal.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="hidUid" value="<?php echo (intval($uid)); ?>"/>

<?php
// Sanitise security addition
if (is_int(intval($uid))){$uid = intval($uid);}else{$uid = 0;}
if ($uid != '')
{
    $date_array = getdate();
    foreach ($date_array as $key => $val) {$key = $val;}
    $mon=$date_array['mon'];
    if($mon<10){$mon="0$mon";}
    $day=$date_array['mday'];
    if($day<10){$day="0$day";}
    $year=$date_array['year'];
    $hrs=$date_array['hours'];
    if($hrs<10){$hrs="0$hrs";}
    $min=$date_array['minutes'];
    if($min<10){$min="0$min";}
    $sec=$date_array['seconds'];
    if($sec<10){$sec="0$sec";}
    $time="$hrs:$min:$sec";
    // date = month/day/year 10/05/2006
    if ($setting['date_format'] == 'day/month/year'){
       $day_mon_yr = "$day/$mon/$year";
       $date = "$day-$mon-$year";
    }
    if ($setting['date_format'] == 'month/day/year'){
       $day_mon_yr = "$mon/$day/$year";
       $date = "$mon-$day-$year";
    }
    if ($setting['date_format'] == 'year/month/day'){
       $day_mon_yr = "$year/$mon/$day";
       $date = "$year-$mon-$day";
    }

    echo '<table align="left" valign="top" width="255" style="margin-top: 0px;">';

    if(isset($_SESSION['s_username']))
    {
       echo '<tr><td width="10">&nbsp;</td><td style="border: 1px solid #666666; background: #fff; padding: 12px;">';

        // loop through the monitors the user has and display them in the menu
       $get_items     = "SELECT * FROM servers WHERE user_id='$uid'";
       $get_items_res = mysql_query($get_items) or die(mysql_error( ));

       if(isset($_SESSION['s_username']))
       {
?>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                var dataString = 'ajax=1&page=' + <?php echo $page?> + '&uid=<?php echo $uid;?>';
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "GET",
                     url: "monpanel.php",
                     data: dataString,
                     success: function(html_data){
                        $('#list_monitors').html(html_data);
                    }
                 });
            </script>
<?php       
            echo '<div id="list_monitors">';
            echo "</div>";

           // chaeck if the user logged in is a paid customer
           #$get_paid     = "SELECT paid FROM servers WHERE user_id='$uid' LIMIT 1";
           #$get_paid_res = mysql_query($get_paid) or die(mysql_error( ));
           while ($item_paid = mysql_fetch_array ($get_items_res)) 
           {
                $paid_array = $item_paid['paid'];
                $paid = $paid_array[0];
           }

           if ($paid == "1")
           {
?>
               <div id="monitor_form"> 
                <fieldset border="0">
                <table align="left">
                  <form name="addmonitor" action=""> <!-- action="user_add.php" method="POST" -->
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><font color="#666666"><strong>Add new monitor:</strong></font></td>
                    </tr>

                    <input type="hidden" name="cemail" id="cemail" value="<?=$_SESSION['s_username']?>" />
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="domain" id="domain_label" style="text-align: left;">Website URL/IP<br>
                        <font size="1" color="red">without http://www.</font></label></td>
                        <td valign="top"><input type="text" size="13" name="domain" id="domain" class="text-input" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label class="error" for="domain" id="domain_error">Field is required.</label></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="com_domain" id="com_domain_label" style="text-align: left;">Monitor Name</label></td>
                        <td valign="top"><input type="text" size="13" name="com_domain" id="com_domain" class="text-input" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label class="error" for="com_domain" id="com_domain_error">Field is required.</label></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="port" id="port_label" style="text-align: left;">Port</label></td>
                        <td valign="top"><select name="port" id="port" class="select-input">

                            <option value="80" SELECTED>HTTP: 80</option>
                            <option value="443">HTTPS: 443</option>
                            <option value="21">FTP: 21</option>
                            <option value="5060">SIP: 5060</option>
                            <option value="80">TCP: 80</option>
                            <option value="5060">UDP: 5060</option>
                            <option value="143">IMAP: 143</option>
                            <option value="25">SMTP: 25</option>
                            <option value="110">POP3: 110</option>

                            </select></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <input type="hidden" name="active" id="active" value="1" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid" value="<?php echo $uid;?>" />
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="main" id="main_label" style="text-align: left;">Main<br>
                        <font size="1" color="red">only one per URL/IP</font></label></td>
                        <td valign="top"><select name="main" id="main" class="select-input">

                                <option value="0">No</option>
                                <option value="1">Yes</option>

                                </select></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Add monitor" name="addserver" class="button" id="addserver_btn" /></td> <!-- name="addserver"  -->
                    </tr>

                    </form>
                </table>
                </fieldset>
               </div>  
               <?php
           }
           else if ($paid == "0")
           {
               ?>
               <div id="free"> 
                <fieldset border="0">
                <table align="left">
                  <form name="free" action=""> <!-- action="user_add.php" method="POST" -->
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><font color="#666666"><strong>Add new monitor:</strong></font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="free" id="free" style="text-align: left;">Website URL/IP<br>
                        <font size="1" color="red">without http://www.</font></label></td>
                        <td valign="top"><input type="text" size="13" name="free" id="free" class="text-input" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="free1" id="free1" style="text-align: left;">Monitor Name</label></td>
                        <td valign="top"><input type="text" size="13" name="free1" id="free1" class="text-input" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="free2" id="free2" style="text-align: left;">Port</label></td>
                        <td valign="top"><select name="free2" id="free2" class="select-input">

                            <option value="80" SELECTED>HTTP: 80</option>
                            <option value="443">HTTPS: 443</option>
                            <option value="21">FTP: 21</option>
                            <option value="5060">SIP: 5060</option>
                            <option value="80">TCP: 80</option>
                            <option value="5060">UDP: 5060</option>
                            <option value="143">IMAP: 143</option>
                            <option value="25">SMTP: 25</option>
                            <option value="110">POP3: 110</option>

                            </select></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="free3" id="free3" style="text-align: left;">Main<br>
                        <font size="1" color="red">only one per URL/IP</font></label></td>
                        <td valign="top"><select name="free3" id="free3" class="select-input">

                                <option value="0">No</option>
                                <option value="1">Yes</option>

                                </select></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Add monitor" name="free4" class="button" id="free4" 
                    onClick="pay=dhtmlmodal.open('pay', 'div', 'paydiv', 'Paid Account', 'width=425px,height=267px,center=1,resize=0,scrolling=0'); return false" /></td> <!-- name="addserver"  -->
                    </tr>
                    </form>
                </table>
                </fieldset>
               </div>

               <div id="paydiv" style="display:none">
                <center>
                <h4>To monitor more websites subscribe to our advanced service:</h4>
                1) You get to set up monitors for an <b>unlimited number of websites</b><br>2) Unlimited alert emails<br>3) Unlimited alert SMS messages<br>4) and much more for only $5 per month...<br><br>
                <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="GDTCMF9N56TKG">
                <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">
                <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                </form>
                <br><br>
                </center>
               </div>
               <?php
           }
           echo '<br><table><b>Account:</b></table>';
           echo '<table>';
           ?>
           <tr><td><img src="images/user.png" title="Edit Profile" alt="Edit Profile">
           <a href="#" title="Click to edit profile" onClick="editprofile=dhtmlwindow.open('editprofile', 'iframe', 'edit_profile.php', 'Edit profile', 'width=430px,height=267px,center=1,resize=0,scrolling=0'); return false">Edit Profile</a><br>
           <img src="images/lock.png" title="Change Password" alt="Change Password">
           <a href="#" title="Click to change password" onClick="changepassword=dhtmlwindow.open('changepassword', 'iframe', 'change_password.php', 'Change password', 'width=370px,height=120px,center=1,resize=0,scrolling=0'); return false">Change Password</a><br>
           <img src="images/monitor_go.png" title="Logout" alt="Logout">&nbsp;<a href="logout.php">Logout</a></tr></td></table>
           </table>
        <?php

        }
    }
}
else
{
   echo '<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />';
   echo '<center><strong>Sorry, You have accessed this page improperly and your access has been logged.</strong></center>';
}
include_once('footer.php');

end;
?>
```

and the javascript file (only the relevant function):

```
// Exibit no.1
 $(function() {  

   $(".button").click(function() {  
     // validate and process form here  

     $('.error').hide();  
       var domain = $("input#domain").val();  
        if (domain == "") {  
       $("label#domain_error").show();  
       $("input#domain").focus();  
       return false;  
     }  
        var com_domain = $("input#com_domain").val();  
         if (com_domain == "") {  
       $("label#com_domain_error").show();  
       $("input#com_domain").focus();  
       return false;  
     }  
        var cemail = $("input#cemail").val();
        var port = $("select#port").val();
        var active = $("input#active").val();
        var uid = $("input#uid").val();
        var main = $("select#main").val();

     var dataString = 'cemail='+ cemail + '&domain=' + domain + '&com_domain=' + com_domain + '&active=' + active + '&main=' + main + '&port=' + port;  
     //alert (dataString);return false;      

     $.ajax({  
       type: "POST",  
       url: "user_add.php",  
       data: dataString,  
       success: function() {  
         $('#monitor_form').append("<div id='message'></div>"); 
         $('#monitor_form form')[0].reset();
         $('#message').html("<img id='checkmark' src='images/tick.png' /><b> Monitor sucessfully added!</b>")  
         .hide()  
         .fadeIn(500, function() {  
           $('#message').append("");  
         });
         setTimeout("$('#message').hide().remove();", 6000);

         var dataString2 = 'ajax=1&uid=' + uid;
         $.ajax({
             async: false,
             type: "GET",
             dataType: "html",
             url: "monpanel.php",
             data: dataString2,
             success: function(html_data){
                $('#list_monitors',top.document).html(html_data);
            }
         });
         //document.onkeydown = showDown;
       }  
     });  
     return false; 
   });  
 }); 

function showDown(evt) {
    event = (evt)? evt : ((event)? event : null);
    if (evt) {
        if (event.keyCode == 8 && (event.srcElement.type!= "text" && event.srcElement.type!= "textarea" && event.srcElement.type!= "password")) {
            // When backspace is pressed but not in form element
            cancelKey(evt);
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == 116) {
            // When F5 is pressed
            cancelKey(evt);
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == 122) {
            // When F11 is pressed
            cancelKey(evt);
        }
        else if (event.ctrlKey && (event.keyCode == 78 || event.keyCode == 82)) {
            // When ctrl is pressed with R or N
            cancelKey(evt);
        }
        else if (event.altKey && event.keyCode==37 ) {
            // stop Alt left cursor
            return false;
        }
    }
} 

function cancelKey(evt) {
    if (evt.preventDefault) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        evt.keyCode = 0;
        evt.returnValue = false;
    }
}
```

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: Well maybe if you can all see the operation first hand, you might see what is wrong... login at uptimeology.com/monitor with testingtest33 and open a few monitors that exist (click on the URL name) and then add a new monitor (URL) through the form. You'll see that the page and the iframe windows reload...

Comment: The username for above is water-car@hotmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not forget to prevent the default handler:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="myAjaxFunction(); return false" />
```

Comment: That makes sense. I'll do something like that. Thank you.

Comment: Tried that. here's my code in the form: <input type="submit" value="Add monitor" name="addserver" class="button" id="addserver_btn" onclick="myAjaxFunction(); return false" /> and my code in the javascript file: $(function myAjaxFunction() {  

   $('.button').click(function() {  
     // validate and process form here  
  ...                                                        Unfortunately the main page is still being reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Does `$(".button")` have it's href set to #? If so, that'll refresh the page. I suggest using something like:

```
$(".button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: This is the button: `code`<input type="submit" value="Add monitor" name="addserver" class="button" id="addserver_btn" and the target of the form submit: `code`<form name="addmonitor" action=""> I don't know if that would force a page reload...

Comment: The fact it is a submit button would. :) 
That's the thing - it's submitting the form... you might want to add an event listener to the submit event of the form rather than to the click of the button :)

Comment: So basically not look for $(".button").click but to implement something else. What kind of even listener would you recommend?

Comment: Did you try adding the line that I mentioned?

Comment: I did but it doesn't get passed the function(e). It doesn't know what e is and the e.preventDefault(); then doesn't work. It did not process the form - did not access the lines beneath this.